# PHP - Advise on large data validation and Imports

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2012

Im currently working on a price import function from excel and looking for advise on the best way to handle the large data sets between PHP and SQL.

Basically a User can import a single file to update ALL thier price lists (up to 15). So a row of example data might look like

MEMBER CODE|PRICELIST1 PRICE|PRICELIST2 PRICE|PRICELIST3 PRICE|PRICELIST4 PRICE

These files can contain up to 30 000 unique records. Where the problem comes in is this data needs to be validated and give back to the user in a table with certain cells highlighted where the price change for the value is greater than a 40% increase.

The products are stored in multiple tables so the query to get the pricelist values for a single line can take up to a second. Initially I tried fetching all the records together(which also takes some time) but if the file has more than 10000 records it gets too large for sql server to handle.

Currently I have it working but extremely slowly (1000 records takes 9minutes to validate), And I am validating a single record at a time.

If anyone has suggestions on how to speed up this process, or has any advise on how best to handle such a large validation process I would greatly apreciate it. Im not closed to any ideas aslong as they are resource friendly and faster.

Comment: i just made something similar a while ago. First imported all the files in a temporary table. Populated it with necessary data like product IDs etc., added indizes. And then the validation was just writing SQL-Command comparing existing data with the temporary data. Also that way you can paginate and sort your import data for displaying to the user. Or just say too many records, click here to download full report.

Comment: Not exactly an answer (hence why this is a comment) but could you import the data into a temporary table on the SQL server, run the comparison query in T-SQL and then return the data to the PHP? I would guess that the comparison would run quicker on the SQL than on PHP due to the lack of moving data around from SQL to PHP etc

Comment: Thanks guys i'll give that a shot shortly sounds like it might just work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With many thanks to [Jens Schulze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4763768/jens-schulze) and [DaveyBoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/896946/daveyboy) i have found an amazing solution. I now write the data to a csv file on the server and use [sqls bulk import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) function to import the data into a temp table and use a query to cross  reference the data before dropping the table. The result is blazingly fast (0.3 seconds to create a file with 20000 records insert it into a table select the records and drop it once the server has the data) an example is below.

THE CSV FORMAT (Place the file in C:\csvtest.txt)

```
1,TD015022,9000.00,9000.00,9000.00,9000.00,9000.00,9000.00 
2,TD015023,7.00,7.00,7.00,7.00,7.00,7.00 
3,TD015024,14.00,14.00,14.00,14.00,14.00,14.00 
4,TD015025,9000.00,9000.00,9000.00,9000.00,9000.00,9000.00
```

THE SQL

```
CREATE TABLE CSVTest
(ID INT,
Member_Code VARCHAR(40),
[Frank Test] VARCHAR(40),
[Price List 1] VARCHAR(40),
[Price List 2] VARCHAR(40),
[Price List 3] VARCHAR(40),
[Ten Percent] VARCHAR(40),
[thaka bts test] VARCHAR(40)
)
GO

BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest
GO
--Drop the table to clean up database.
DROP TABLE CSVTest
GO
```

Hope this helps the next person whos stuck.
Also with thanks to [sqlauthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) for a working example to get started.

Comment: I can only do this tomorrow,

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't know. :)